# Use of count variable in register_chrdev_region

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, drivers

As of I understand, the signature of the `register_chrdev_region` is described as follows

```
extern int register_chrdev_region(dev_t firstmajor,unsigned int count,const char*dev_name);
//firstmajor: The major number requested for reservation of the dirver
//dev_name: Name of the device associated with the major number(for procfs and sysfs)
//count: Total number of contagious device numbes that is requested??
```

I don't get the usage of `count` arguement in the function (in `alloc_chrdev_region` as well). Please explain a simple use case of reserving contagious device numbers for the driver

Reference 3.2.2 in http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-3-sect-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment said:

```
/**     
 * alloc_chrdev_region() - register a range of char device numbers
 * @dev: output parameter for first assigned number
 * @baseminor: first of the requested range of minor numbers
 * @count: the number of minor numbers required
 * @name: the name of the associated device or driver
 *      
 * Allocates a range of char device numbers.  The major number will be
 * chosen dynamically, and returned (along with the first minor number)
 * in @dev.  Returns zero or a negative error code.
 */
```

and you can find an example in fs/fuse/cuse.c:

```
/* determine and reserve devt */
devt = MKDEV(arg->dev_major, arg->dev_minor);
if (!MAJOR(devt))
        rc = alloc_chrdev_region(&devt, MINOR(devt), 1, devinfo.name);
else
        rc = register_chrdev_region(devt, 1, devinfo.name);
if (rc) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "CUSE: failed to register chrdev region\n");
        goto err;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Count is the number of minor numbers allocated to this major number or this driver
          **While creating device nodes its user responsibility to create the device node with permissible minor numbers(it should be less than count)**

Ex:
          if we create driver with first number as 0 and count as 2, kernel allocates 0 to 2 minor numbers to this driver.
          But user still can create a device node with minor number greater than 2.
          If minor number is greater than 2 kernel cannot access the driver for that device node because this minor number is not registered, so it cannot open the device node and throw error when you want to do file operations on that device node.